# (Google Sheets) IF Cell1 has STRING AND Cell2 has STRING then return TRUE OR FALSE

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to streamline my company's booking system (TOURISM). A lot of our backend is mostly done by hand and I'm trying to automate as many processes as possible.

In one such example, we have a Google Sheet that we use to keep a log of people's hotel bookings during tours. Customers have the option to either let us choose their hotels or they can book it themselves. Using mail merge I plan on sending out an email automatically 2 weeks prior to the tour date to make sure people who have selected to "BOOK THEIR OWN" hotels have done so and can send us confirmation.

I'm not sure exactly what function I should use to get a cell to represent whether a customer has successfully booked or not.

Here is an example of our booking system

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwyVp.png

So what I want to do is in a new column called "Checker" I would like to have a function that checks whether the cell "Room Type" (F#) contains the text "BOOKING OWN", if this is true and the cell "Accom Name" (G#) is empty then I would like the text "Pending" to be displayed in the "Checker" cell, if this statement is false then I would like the box to stay blank.

I expect it would look something like

=IF(AND(F29= "BOOKING OWN",G29 = ""), "Pending")

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your formula. You might want to change it to this to avoid returning 'false':

=IF(AND(F29= "BOOKING OWN",G29 = ""), "Pending","")

You could also use an array formula like this instead:

```
=iferror(ArrayFormula(IF((F4:F= "BOOKING OWN")*(G4:G = ""), "Pending","")),"")
```